# Magento API Extension returns null only when result set programmatically

Tags: php, xml, api, magento

OK, so this is a strange one for me, I have added a custom method to the Magento Core API and it is working fine, except for when I try to set results programmatically:

```
 public function infoByOmsId($omsId){

    $customer_model = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer_model->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer_model->loadByOmsId($omsId);

    $result = array();
    $result['customer_id'] = $customer_model->getId();//51;

    return $result;
```

If I hard code the value, it comes back in the SOAP response, however, when I set it programmatically, the node for the response value comes back empty.  I have checked the code - by putting it in its own php file and var_dump’ing the customer model - to make sure it is getting a result, and the data elements are there.  I have tried changing the response from an array to just a single string element, and I get the same results.

I originally thought it might be a data type issue because I am using the WSI-compliant, V2 API.  But I changed my response types from an int to a string (I get a string when I var_dump the array in my standalone code) and that doesn’t seem to have worked, either.  I am definitely receiving the “oms_id” - a custom attribute - in to the API, because I am able to just pass it straight back out and I get it back in the response.  I have tried grabbing the value I want from the model a couple of different ways, none have worked to return a value in XML from the API, but all have worked in my standalone php file.:

```
    $customer_model->getData('entity_id');
    $customer_model['entity_id'];
    $customer_model->getId();
```

Here’s my wsdl.xml file:

```
    <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
        <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        <complexType name="customerId">
            <all>
                <element name="customer_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </all>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
</types>
<message name="mycompanyInfoByOmsIdRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="omsId" type="xsd:int" />
</message>
<message name="mycompanyInfoByOmsIdResponse">
    <part name="customer_oms_id" type="xsd:customerId" />
</message>
```

and wsi.xml:

```
    <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
        <xsd:complexType name="mycompanyInfoByOmsId">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="customer_id" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:element name="mycompanyInfoByOmsIdRequestParam">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="omsId" type="xsd:int" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="mycompanyInfoByOmsIdResponseParam">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="typens:mycompanyInfoByOmsId" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

What am I doing wrong that these dynamic values aren’t returning?  Anybody have experience with this?

Comment: I know it sounds crazy, but have you tried logging (`Mage::Log($result);`) in the actual API call?  API code runs in a different context that regular web requests  (ex. different store id set) and I've seen that effect how other code runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No direct experience with this, but I've had to debug several similar issues.  Here's a few tips to help you track this down.

First, I know your tripple checked that your code is returning what you think its returning, but I'd ask you to quadruple check it.  Specifically, instead of running your code in a separate PHP file, **log** values from the actual API call.

```
public function infoByOmsId($omsId){

    $customer_model = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer_model->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer_model->loadByOmsId($omsId);

    $result = array();
    $result['customer_id'] = $customer_model->getId();//51;

    Mage::Log($result);
    Mage::Log($omsId);

    return $result;
}
```

API code runs in a slightly different context than standard web requests (e.x. a store id of "0"), and I've had more than one occasion where code run in an API context retuned different values than code in a standard frontend or adminhtml context.  Also, make sure your code is receiving the `$omsId` correctly.

Second, this does sounds like a possible data type/casting issue to me — it's possible that your changes to your schema were ignored somewhere along the way due to caching.  I'm sure you know about Magento's cache — Magento will cache the generated WSDL. Because of this, anytime you make a configuration change you'll want to clear the cache. (directly deleting from `var/cache` is the best way to go about this from a "be sure the cache is destroyed" standpoint).

In addition to Magento's WSDL cache, **PHP** has a mechanism for caching WSDL files on the both *client* and *server* side.  This has nothing to do with Magento's cache.  So, even if you clear out your Magento cache, in order to ensure everyone is seeing the same WSDL file you'll want/need to clear PHP's WSDL cache files. You can find your PHP WSDL cache files in the tmp directory, prepended with a `wsdl`

```
rm /tmp/wsdl-*
```

This needs to happen on the Magento server, **and** on the client if you're using PHP to make the requests. Ideally, you should turn off PHP's WSDL caching while developing.  Magento added the ability to do this in CE versions 1.7 and greater.

```
System -> Configuration -> Magento Core API -> General Settings -> Enable WSDL Cache
```

Normally, this is controlled by the PHP ini setting `soap.wsdl_cache_enabled`. Some versions of Magento turn this off explicitly (the setting above controls this), and I've seen lots of Magento installations where folks have altered Magento's core to keep this **on**, so you may want to do some `grep`ing through the code.

Finally, if the above two items don't help, I'd start looking directly at the XML SOAP responses sent back by Magento.  Specifically, the XML content for the WSI API is set in

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Wsi/Adapter/Soap.php
public function run()
{
    //big code block to send response to a SOAP request here
    return $this;
}
```

I'd log the raw XML responses (again, with some temporary code added to the core files that you'll remove before deploying)

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Wsi/Adapter/Soap.php
public function run()
{
    //big code block to send response to a SOAP request here

    Mage::log($this->getController()->getResponse());
    return $this;
}
```

and compare your "works ok" examples with your "doesn't work" examples, looking for the XML characters that pass your value back to the web service client.  A good `diff` program will be helpful here.

If there is a serializing problem, this will let you know if it's happening on the Magento side, or on your client library side.

Comment: Thanks, Alan!  This helped a lot. I had to get the customer collection instead since something was wonky with the context.  I ended up solving it this way:

    public function infoByOmsId($omsId){

        $result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('oms_‌​id')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('oms_id',$omsId)->load($omsId);

        foreach ($result as $customer) {
            $id = $customer->getData('entity_id');
        }


        return $id;

    }  Thanks again!

Comment: I love your articles about the API, by the way!  I have learned a lot from them.

Comment: @StephanieRansdell Happy to help — be sure to mark this ash an accepted answer — it'll improve you reputation score on StackOverflow, which in turn will increase the likelihood that folks will answer you next question